# CGAL-bindings: Surface_Mesher weird Triangulations?

Tags: python, image-processing, computational-geometry, cgal

Im trying to replicate a cgal example for gray scale images on my Aorta.inr segmented image that its basically:

```
  1 if the point its inside the Aorta.

  0 if the point its at the outside.
```

But the triangulation its giving me this weird form that its not similar to the input image.

Aorta .inr file with isovalue=1. and the triangulation result:

[image][image]

And its weird because im able to replicate the example with the isovalue given.

Example .inr file from Cgal and in the right the 3d Mesh(with the example params. from https://github.com/gx/CGAL/blob/master/examples/Surface_mesher/mesh_a_3d_gray_image.cpp):

[image][image]

Someone have a clue on what could be happening? It would be so much help please :)

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was the INR file in wich the data needed to be transposed before writing. Now all works fine and my methods "writeINR" and "readINR" are working perfectly!.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you pay attention to correctly choose the squared radius of the bounding sphere and the criteria for your example?

Comment: Have you got a solution to your problem, since you post it?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in my "writeINR" and "readINR" methods. It seems that i needed to transpose the data before writing it in the file, now all its working perfectly. I edited my question with the solution.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to you, create a .inr image with 1 and 0 whether the point is inside or outside. However there seems little to no documentation on how to do it. Do you happen to have found such documentation or do you have an example of your .inr files?

Comment: I didnt find any documentation, i made a code in python myself that creates an INR file. I think i discovered how to do it by looking an example inr file. If you're interested: https://github.com/cncastillo/BioMedUC/blob/master/INRfiles.py

Comment: Thanks for that, that's quite helpful. I have managed to solve most of my issues in the meantime. It seems the only thing left is the same transpose problem you had. Do you just transpose your i,j,k 3D matrix to a k,j,i one and write it to the file?  
Also, where do you put the carriage returns in the data? I currently put each i,j (or k,j after transposition) plane in a row-major order on the same line, then the next k (or i) plane on a new line.

Comment: Disregard this, I've managed to make it work. I only needed to transpose the i,j matrix for each k plane and no line breaks are required despite what the documentation seems to imply. Thanks a lot for the tips.

Comment: Yeah i had a big headache with this 2 years ago, i'm glad that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with two things: the definition of your surface, and the definition of the bounding sphere.

- As for the surface, our code uses the class templates [`CGAL::Gray_level_image_3`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/classCGAL_1_1Gray__level__image__3.html) and [`CGAL::Implicit_surface_3`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/classCGAL_1_1Implicit__surface__3.html) (the links point to the documentation pages). The documentation of `CGAL::Gray_level_image_3` says that the function that is implemented by that class is: `sign(f(p)-iso)`. If your image has all pixels with values `0` or `1`, and the isovalue is 1, then `f(p)-iso` is either `-1` or `0`, and the sign of it is never `+1`. That is why I suggest you use `0.5` as isovalue, instead of `1`.
- As for the bounding sphere, verify that the center of the sphere and its **squared** radius are chosen so that all the cube of the image is inside the sphere. Otherwise, your object will be clipped by the sphere.

I do not really understand the result you get with your Aorta surface, but I am pretty sure that you will find out that either the definition of the surface, or the bounding sphere, was wrong.